# Sending message to a particular contact on Whatsapp from android app

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to send a message to a particular contact on WhatsApp from my android app.
I am able to do the same, but while sending it asks for opening with chrome and WhatsApp; I don't want the app to ask and instead directly open Whatsapp.

This opens specified contact on Whatsapp with specified phone number and pre-fills with the message.[image]

[image: What has to be written in here in place of the question mark for the **className**]

What has to be written in here in place of the question mark for the **className**
for example in case of opening facebook app, we write "sharingIntent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana",
                    "**com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity**");"

Comment: show the code when it asks to choose app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may send your intent to specific package by adding

```
intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```

So you may just use same code which offeres to choose between chrome and WhatsApp, but adding the method above.

Answer (score 1):

> Try using Intent.EXTRA_TEXT instead of sms_body as your extra key. Per WhatsApp's documentation, this is what you have to use.

An example from their [website](https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/28000012):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Their example uses Intent.ACTION_SEND instead of Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, so I'm not sure if WhatsApp even supports sending directly to a contact via the intent system. Some quick testing should let you determine that.

Answer (score 0):

> try this :

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```